# Font size different in \newtheorem heading and body text versus the rest of the document

Tags: fonts, size

I am using the book document class with no font size specified, so it should be the default 10pt.

After \begin{document} I have the line \fontsize{9}{10.8} to change all the font to 9pt.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  %{\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {8pt}
  {8pt}
  {}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\counterwithin*{test}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{9}{10.8}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This font looks to be 9pt.

\begin{test}
This is the test.  This seems to come out smaller.
\end{test}


\end{document}
```

The heading "Test" and the body text are smaller than the 9pt specified in \fontsize.

What smaller font size is this?  And can I get the entire document to output in this smaller font size with \fontsize?  Or is \fontsize causing these two sizes of fonts?

Comment: It is impossible to debug disconnected fragments, Please edit the question so that it has a small but complete document that shows the issue. Remove any packages that are not needed to show the problem.

Comment: You are missing `\selectfont` after the `\fontsize` declaration. The "smaller" size is in fact the requested 9pt. But this is not the best way to set a smaller font size for the whole document, as any macro calling `\normalsize` will revert to 10pt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `\fontsize{9}{10.8}` doesn't take effect until `\selectfont` is issued. This happens in the theorem, but not in the text above it.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  %{\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {8pt}
  {8pt}
  {}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\counterwithin*{test}{subsection}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{9}{10.8}\selectfont

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This font looks to be 9pt.

\begin{test}
This is the test.  This seems to come out smaller.
\end{test}


\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, using a specialized class for this seems better.

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{extbook}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
  %{\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {8pt}
  {8pt}
  {}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\counterwithin*{test}{subsection}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. This font looks to be 9pt.

\begin{test}
This is the test.  This seems to come out smaller.
\end{test}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Perfect.